# loading xml document fails with special character &raquo;

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, rss

I'm consuming an RSS feed and the document contains a special character »

I'm guessing the feed is not encoded properly but I can't change that.  I'd like to override that or just replace the offending char with something friendly.

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load(reader);  //<--- FAILS HERE
                    //parse the items of the feed
```

...

Comment: You can check this post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700686/an-error-occurred-while-parsing-entityname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700686/an-error-occurred-while-parsing-entityname)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&raquo;` is an [HTML named entity](http://www.fileformat.info/format/w3c/htmlentity.htm) and is not supported in XML. Out of the box, XML [only supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) `&amp;`, `&apos;`, `&quot;`, `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

Use the corresponding numeric entity `&#187;` (or hexadecimal `&#xbb;`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

+1 what Frédéric said. You can also serve `»` as a raw unescaped character, presumably encoded in UTF-8.

If it's someone else's RSS feed, you need to kick them to stop producing malformed XML; no XML parser will read this.

In a `<description>` element, the HTML content should normally be XML-escaped. So if the description of the item is `This is a <em>really</em> interesting article`, it should appear in the XML as:

```
<description>This is a &lt;em>really&lt;/em> interesting article</description>
```

Consequently, an HTML-encoded `»` character should have come out as

```
&amp;raquo;
```

If it was included directly from an HTML source without being escaped, that's a more serious XML-injection problem.

(This is assuming RSS 2.0. In the various earlier versions of RSS, whether the `<description>` contained HTML or plain text varied from spec to spec and was sometimes completely unspecified. For old RSS versions it's not really reliable to use HTML content at all.)

Comment: I guess we should be kicking Google for pumping out RSS 2 with these issues then: http://feeds.feedburner.com/robinsloan