# Why am I getting this error in XML file?

Tags: xml

I am wrtting an XML file in Java

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: file:///home/Desktop/desk.xml
Line Number 13, Column 13:<a>example &raquo; FEEDBACK</a>
------------^
```

Why does it say `&raquo;` is an undefined entity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading xml document fails with special character &raquo;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130865/loading-xml-document-fails-with-special-character-raquo)

Answer (score 2):

Does your XML have any schema? The schema has to define the entity. XML has only a few entities out of the box:

- & `amp`
- ' `apos`
- " `quot`
- > `gt`
- < `lt`

All other are from a schema like [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/).

Answer (score 0):

Reason: `&raquo` is a element of XSLT2.0 stylesheet...

solution 1:

Replace your xml entity `&raquo;` with the numeric entity `&#187;`

OR

Solution 2:

If you want the output document to contain the named HTML entity `&raquo;` rather than the numeric reference, add the following elements to your stylesheet (XSLT2.0 only)